# using volatile keyword in java4 and java5

Tags: java

what is the difference in using `volatile keyword` in java4 and java5 onwards?

and related to that,

> Read/write operations on non-atomic variables(long/double) are atomic when they are 
>   declared as volatile.

Is this also true for java4 **or** it is valid from java5 onwards???

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile

Comment: Why are you assuming there are any differences between java4 and java5 related to the volatile keyword?

Comment: @claesv because there are. The Java Memory Model changed between those versions.

Comment: Being perdantic, the version after Java 1.4 was Java 5.0 followed by Java 6.

Comment: @Luciano I did not know that. Shame on me. And thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People have provided good points and references responding to my question answering first part.

Going specific to the second part of question, this i read at some forum:

> A volatile declared long is atomic (pre-Java 5 also) in the sense that
>   it guarantees (for all JVM implementations) a read or write go
>   directly to main memory instead of two 32-bit registers.

And

> Pre-Java 5, volatile was *supposed* to provide such guarantees for long
>   and double. However things did not work out this way in practice, and
>   implementations frequently violated this guarantee. As I recall the
>   issue seemed to get fixed around JDK 1.4, but as they were still
>   working on the whole memory model thing, they didn't really make any
>   clear announcements about it until JDK 5, when the new rules were
>   announced, and memory guarantees actually meant something.

And this is from **Java  Language Specification,Second Edition**:

> 17.4   Nonatomic Treatment of  double and long
>
> The load, store, read, and write actions on volatile variables are atomic,
>   even if the type of the variable is double or long.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a difference.
Up to Java 4 `volatile` could be re-ordered by compiler with respect to any previous read or write, leading to subtle concurrency bugs e.g. making it impossible to implement a `double check` locking (very common idiom for a Singleton).
This is fixed in Java 5.0 which extends the semantics for `volatile` which cannot be reordered with respect to any following read or write anymore and introduces a new memory model. You can read this [Double Checked Locking](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) for example reference

Answer (score 3):

This site gives a good explanation of the differences: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml

They also give an explanation of the behavior of volatile in Java 5 on a separate page: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_java_5.shtml

Comment: Says the first reference article: "As of Java 5, accessing a volatile variable creates a memory barrier: it effectively synchronizes all cached copies of variables with main memory"

Answer (score 1):

**What is the difference in using volatile keyword in java4 and java5 onwards?**

JMM before JDK5 is broken and using volatile for JDK4 may not provide the intended result. For more check this:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02244/

**Read/write operations on non-atomic variables(long/double) are atomic when they are declared as volatile.**

Read/Write for long/double happen as two separate 32-bit operations. For two threads it is possible that one thread has read higher 32-bits and other one has read lower 32-bits of a long/double variable. In short read/write on long is not atomic operation unlike other primitives.
Using volatile for long/double is supposed to provide such guarantee as the instructions for volatile are not re-ordered for volatile read/write by compiler and volatile also provides visibility guarantee. But again it may not work for JDK 4 or before.