# Why Spring framework preferes mutex over volatile?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, mutex, volatile

```
public abstract class AbstractApplicationContext extends DefaultResourceLoader
        implements ConfigurableApplicationContext, DisposableBean {

   private boolean active = false;
   private final Object activeMonitor = new Object();

   public boolean isActive() {
      synchronized (this.activeMonitor) {
         return this.active;
      }
   }

   protected void cancelRefresh(BeansException ex) {
       synchronized (this.activeMonitor) {
          this.active = false;
       }
   }

   ...
}
```

Is there anything essential in using mutex instead of volatile for read consistency, or it is just the question of preferences / code convention / etc? At first sight, mutex gives nothing new, except we have more lines of code. Also, we can change several variables inside synchronized block, but it is not the issue in the example - only one variable is changed.

P.S. I know what is mutex and volatile, please avoid JMM explanation in answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`volatile` isn't the same as `synchronized`. `volatile` only takes care of the readability of data between threads. `syncronized` also blocks concurrent access in this case.

Also [before JDK 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336006/using-volatile-keyword-in-java4-and-java5) the use/implementation of the `volatile` keyword was not implemented fully or correctly and hence the safer use of mutexes especially in code that has been in Spring since the beginning or before JDK 1.5. This still remains true for code that is in older versions of the framework that need to support Java <= JDK 1.5.

In newer parts of the framework useable by JDK 1.5 or up you will see much more use of either `volatile` or the `Atomic*` classes. In the newer versions supporting only JDK 1.6 and up a lot of cleanup has been done.

Comment: but java 1.5 was released in 2004 and spring 3.2 in almost 2013.. so it took about 10 years to refactor it?

Comment: Spring 3.x was for upgrading the APIs in spring not the actual internals, why fix something that wasn't broken. But the fact is that that code originated from the early versions of spring and hence no atomics or proper volatile.

Comment: so, the bottomline: spring uses mutex, because it is heritage of the past.

Comment: Yes. And in the 4.x line there has been some cleanup for that.

Answer (score 1):

No real reason so possibly just a convention (personal or project's), but they're `AtomicBooleans` in version 4.1.6.

The `active` value is used normally (`get/set`), but there's a `closed` that uses `compareAndSet`.